# Dilation image-recognition algorithms cityScapes model

Tags: python

I am trying to use this image-recognition algorithms using cityScapes model
https://github.com/fyu/dilation

However, I keep on getting the following error:

```
- bash-4.2$ python predict.py cityscapes sunny_1336601.png --gpu 0
Using GPU  0
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "predict.py", line 133, in <module>
main()
File "predict.py", line 129, in main
predict(args.dataset, args.input_path, args.output_path)
File "predict.py", line 98, in predict
color_image = dataset.palette[prediction.ravel()].reshape(image_size)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12582912 into shape (1090,1920,3)
```

I tried reshaping the image to every common resolution I could think of,  including 640x480, but I have been getting the same error.

Any help or tips is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am posting my hunch as an answer (forgive me if I'm wrong) : the given size `12582912` has to be a product of the three numbers in the tuple. A quick factorisation showed `12582912 = 1024*768*16 = 2048*1536*4` So, if the images is a 4-channel image, the resolution is `2048 x 1536` which is in standard 4:3 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Cityscapes model only takes a specific size: The width should be twice the length.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Python well, you will see that ValueError is internal code error. It has nothing to do with missing dependencies or environment.

It has to do with the fact that the image was one total size first, and then it's being casted to array and then back into another dimensions.
That is not something that can be fixed or should be fixed by tempering with input data, but with addressing the bug in the provided library itself.

It is very common to have this kind of restrictions with NN classifier. Because once layers are trained, they can't be changed and the input must be very specific. Of course, it still can be "cooked" before giving it to NN but it's usually nondestructive/basic scaling, so the proportions must be preserved, which is what the library does wrong.